# Intellij 2021.1 - Sencha ExtJS plugin not working

Tags: intellij-idea, extjs, intellij-plugin

With the new Intelij version 2021.1 the Sencha ExtJS plugin stops working again. Do you have an idea if or how we could fix this? The bug in the last version could be fixed through deleting some .jar files from the plugin folder.

```
    com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing plugin com.sencha.idea.IdeaPlugin
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImplKt.handleComponentError(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:1075)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexDataInitialization.lambda$initAssociatedDataForExtensions$0(FileBasedIndexDataInitialization.java:88)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexDataInitializer.executeTask(IndexDataInitializer.kt:75)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexDataInitializer.access$executeTask(IndexDataInitializer.kt:15)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexDataInitializer$runParallelTasks$$inlined$map$lambda$1.run(IndexDataInitializer.kt:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:216)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:27)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:195)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:213)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:184)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Index com.intellij.indexing.shared.platform.impl.CompositeInvertedIndex@5b5e859 already registered for the name 'sencha.view_model.index' [Plugin: com.sencha.idea.IdeaPlugin]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Index com.intellij.indexing.shared.platform.impl.CompositeInvertedIndex@5b5e859 already registered for the name 'sencha.view_model.index'
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexConfiguration.registerIndex(IndexConfiguration.java:83)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initIndexStorage(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:488)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.registerIndexer(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:439)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexDataInitialization.lambda$initAssociatedDataForExtensions$0(FileBasedIndexDataInitialization.java:79)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1):

4-sep-2021 update
Thanks for using Sencha Support.
This is a known issue. Bug id IDEAPLUGIN-391.
Until this issue is resolved please downgrade to the last 2020 release for PhpStorm.
We apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

I believe IDEAPLUGIN-391 has been resolved. I just installed sjp-6.0.15.628.zip and it seems to work fine with Jetbrains 2021.2.3 versions of pycharm and webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this plugin is not maintained anymore.
If you check `https://docs.sencha.com/ide_plugins/guides/jetbrains_ide_plugin.html` then you can see this list:

```
Please use version 6.0.12 for 2018.2+ releases of Jetbrains IDEs
Please use version 6.0.11 for 2016.1+ releases of JetBrains IDEs
Please use version 6.0.8 for the following releases of JetBrains IDEs:
```

Also here on jetbrains page it looks like they didn't provide version for IntelliJ 2021.1 yet
`https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7740-sencha-ext-js/versions`

I don't recommend using a non-maintained library and keep looking for shady fixes, perhaps just go with Visual Code editor without IntelliJ support for this JS lib.

Comment: I've created a support ticket at Sencha and got this answer:
"Thank you for contacting Sencha Support. We have already identified this issue and are in the process of attempting to update our module to work with 2021 releases of IntelliJ products. I have attached a link to the bug report to the Issues section of this ticket (bottom/right) for you to monitor. Unfortunately we do not have any work around for this save to rollback to an earlier release of your IntelliJ product.". 
According to the mentioned bug report they are working on it since 8th April, but it's still open.

Comment: @Mark This happens pretty much _every_ IntelliJ update.  I think they will actually fix it, but it seems people need to complain before they do.  They won't just follow IntelliJ updates and have an update ready.

Comment: @Mark There is a nightly version `6.0.14.622` (from 2021-05-25), but that doesn't work in IntelliJ 2021.1 either.  So, I assume they are working on it, but I also assume it'll take a few weeks before we get an updated plugin.

Comment: @RocketHazmat at least it seems like they started working. Hopefully they wont need to much time to fix and release it. This happens with each Intellij version which is really sad since this is a payed product...

Comment: For anyone looking into this, as of 2021-08-09, the issue is still present.

Comment: I just don't understand why paying for an ExtJS licence since they don't maintain tools that can help developpers. I use IntelliJ and I don't want to install another IDE just for Ext.

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliJ Version 2021.3 the plugin is still not updated. You need to downgrade to 2021.2.4 to avoid the error. May have an update in the future resolving this.
[Sencha Ext JS Plugin Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4AZW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed PHPStorm 2021.3.1 and the Sencha ExtJS plugin in version 6.0.15.628.

- remove old plugin folder `sencha-jetbrains-plugin` in `/home/yourname/.local/share/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.3`
- download the newest version of sencha plugin from `support.sencha.com`
- copy the downloaded folder `sencha-jetbrains-plugin` in `/home/yourname/.local/share/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.3`
- go to `/home/yourname/.local/share/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.3/sencha-jetbrains-plugin/lib` and remove all files that contain groovy in their name
- start PhpStorm

PhpStorm has his own groovy.jar files.

The plugin will work now (Ext JS requirements will be filled automatically). But there is a new deprecated warning, which appears on start. So there will be new problems soon.